# 'GifImageFile' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to apologize in advance if this has been asked a lot, but I still cant find an answer that can help me. I'm still pretty new at python. What I'm trying to do is iterate image by image through a list of images and resize and convert the images to grayscale. The error I'm getting though is "'GifImageFile' object is not iterable" even though it shows it worked through each image in an output. The original print(images) is to show the images before, and the print(images2) is to show the images after.

```
def sanitize(images) :
images2 = []
print (images)
for image in images :
    images2.append(grayscale(image.resize((64, 48), Image.ANTIALIAS)).convert("L"))
    #images2.append(image)
print(images2)
return to_np_array(images2)
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Please select picture you would like to compare: 12
[<PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile image mode=P size=63x48 at 0x2A9F46C1E10>, 
<PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile image mode=P size=63x48 at 0x2A9F460CBE0>, 
<PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile image mode=P size=63x48 at 0x2A9F460C9B0>, 
<PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile image mode=P size=63x48 at 0x2A9F460C940>, 
<PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile image mode=P size=63x48 at 0x2A9F460C6D8>, 
<PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile image mode=P size=63x48 at 0x2A9F460CB70>] 


[<PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=64x48 at 0x2A9F46CF080>, 
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=64x48 at 0x2A9F46CF0F0>, <PIL.Image.Image 
image mode=L size=64x48 at 0x2A9F46CF128>, <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L 
size=64x48 at 0x2A9F46CFF60>, <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=64x48 at 
0x2A9F485F080>, <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=64x48 at 0x2A9F485F0F0>]
here
<PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile image mode=P size=63x48 at 0x2A9F46C1EF0> 


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-eda50e2d5891>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/andre/Desktop/CSE 535 Final/Code/main.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/andre/Desktop/CSE 535 Final/Code')

  File "C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3.0\lib\site-
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3.0\lib\site-
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/andre/Desktop/CSE 535 Final/Code/main.py", line 36, in 
<module>
    ct.verify_face(image)

  File "C:\Users\andre\Desktop\CSE 535 Final\Code\control.py", line 57, in 
verify_face
    np_image = ut.sanitize(image)

  File "C:\Users\andre\Desktop\CSE 535 Final\Code\utils.py", line 77, in 
sanitize
    for image in images :

TypeError: 'GifImageFile' object is not iterable
```

Thank you for your time. I really appreciate it.